# Issue getting context menu in adobe CQ5 with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, aem

I am trying to automate Adobe CQ5 with Selenium webdriver.
I am finding it difficult to right click on content pages on right hand pane.

If anyone succeeded working with context menu on right hand pane/content pages, please guide me with approach which worked.
Let me provide you more details of the issue I am facing:

I have article with the name 'MyArticle' and I am trying to right click and open it. When I am using below piece of code I am not getting context menu itself so that I can work on it.

```
    Actions action = new Actions(myD);
    WebElement wb =myD.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td/div[contains(text(),'MyArticle')]"));

    Action rightClick = action.contextClick(wb).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build();
    rightClick.perform();
```

I tried different ways but getting error while locating the element, any clue would be really helpful.

Thanks,
Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question. I am assuming you are in WCM, trying to open a page for editing.

The code below works for me in CQ 5.6, Selenium 2.25 in both IE and FF.

```java
WebElement tableRow = driver.findElement(By.id("cq-siteadmin-grid"))
                             .findElement(By.xpath(".//div[text()='YOUR_PAGE_TITLE_HERE']"));
new Actions(driver).contextClick(tableRow).perform();           
WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'x-menu') and contains(@style, 'visible')]"));
menu.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[text()='Open']")).click();
```

Let me know if it helped.